After updating to Expo sdk 52 getting this error -> NOBRIDGE) ERROR Cannot read property 'add' of undefined (NOBRIDGE) ERROR undefined
I have an app being developed using expo and react native . for the Api's we are using wundergraph - we generate the client using the template-> templates.typescript.client.
We have the following dependencies for wundergraph
"@wundergraph/metro-config": "^0.0.1",
"@wundergraph/sdk": "^0.184.2",
"@wundergraph/swr": "^0.19.3",
"swr": "^2.2.5",
It was working fine with expo sdk 51.
since we are not able to continue using expo go , i tried updating the expo sdk and other deps using
npm install expo@latest
npx expo install --fix
currently on some mutations we get "TypeError: Cannot read the property 'add' of undefined.
If we revert back to the previous expo sdk 51 and the earlier deps everything works fine ( we are able to test on a development build using devclient )

Same issue for me. I also use swr. It worked fine before Expo 52. It throw TypeError: Cannot read the property 'add' of undefined after upgrade to Expo 52.

Find this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/47730#issuecomment-2495544910. We may need to wait until this issue is fixed.
